# Tableview cell with textfields and button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableviewcell that has two text fields and a button. 
The idea is that you fill in the text field, but the button will bring up another viewcontroller that has some sort of calculator.

My problem comes with bringing the value back into the right cell and textfield.

I get at the button click with this in the Configure cell;

```
[cell setDidTapButtonBlock:^(id sender) {
    [self countNotes:cashoutLine.cashCurrency cell:cell];

}];
```

This calls this extract of code;

```
-(void)countNotes:(Currency *)cashCurrency cell:(PouchEntryViewCell *)cell
{

    NotesCountViewController *notesCountVC = [[NotesCountViewController alloc] init];
    notesCountVC.noteCurrency = cashCurrency;

    notesCountVC.notesDelegate = self;

     notesCountVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:notesCountVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

All good and the new viewcontroller shows up.
I do the work there and pass back the total using delegate. It arrives happily in the first view controller, but then I'm stuck.
How can I get it to populate the correct cell?

Comment: See this answer I gave for similar question. Set tag value on UIButton control in your case and use this value to figure out which cell to update after calculation dialog. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271370/uitableviewcell-receive-stepper-instance-value/23273175#23273175

Comment: Pasas and copy of the index path into the NotesCountViewController via a custom initMethod. Then return that index path in the delegate callback...

Comment: Tag is a short-sighted way to go about things. You will lose your section if you only set a tag with a row. You're passing in the cell, why not pass in the index path as well and pass it back in your delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're presenting the calculator from the ViewController that acts as the UITableViewDataSource delegate, you can find the correct cell to update the textfield by creating a NSIndexPath property in your NotesCountViewController. Before you present the view controller, set the property. When it is dismissed, pass the NSIndexPath back to your UITableViewDataSource viewController, and find the correct cell with that.

```
-(void)countNotes:(Currency *)cashCurrency cell:(PouchEntryViewCell *)cell atIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NotesCountViewController *notesCountVC = [[NotesCountViewController alloc] init];
    notesCountVC.noteCurrency = cashCurrency;

    notesCountVC.cellIndexPath = indexPath;

    notesCountVC.notesDelegate = self;
    notesCountVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:notesCountVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then get the cell in the Delegate callback with

```
PouchEntryViewCell *cell = (PouchEntryViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textField.text = @"New Text";
```

Comment: This is getting close, but I get a waring in the delegate method coming back, and nothing shows up on the field.  Incompatible pointer types initializing 'PouchEntryViewCell *' with an expression of type 'UITableViewCell *'

Comment: Sorry, was doing a tableview reload. Once that was taken out it comes into the right field. Still have the warning thou - ignoring it :)  Thanks a million

Comment: Glad it works! You can cast the cell type to get rid of the compiler warning. See my edited answer above.

Comment: I actually skipped passing the cell altogether. All that was needed was the indexPath.

Comment: After filling in the values in the tableview, I process them in textFieldDidEndEditing and load it straight into a NSDict. Works great for all except the last one. I have a Done button that the user clicks when all the values are in, but the last one wont give up it's data (as it hasn't EndEditing) - Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In `NotesCountViewController`

```
- (id) initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.indexPath = indexPath;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Declare this in your .h and also add an indexPath property.. Then just add the self.indexPath in your delegate call back.

To call it just do:

```
NotesCountViewController *notesCountViewController = [[NotesCountViewController alloc] initWithIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Then to retrieve the cell in the del callback:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```